# ValueError: Length of values (1670) does not match length of index (1440)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data such as name, price, features, discount, ratings from flipkart website. It's getting scraped properly but when I am trying to convert it to the dataframe using pandas I am getting the error as **ValueError: Length of values (1670) does not match length of index (1440)**. I am searching for mobiles and on the first page there are total of 24 results and additional 5 results are coming at the bottom. I checked the name field is taking 24 data but the price field is taking 29 additional 5 data also it's taking. What should I do so that it price fields does not takes up the bottom data.
Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
res = requests.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=samsung+mobiles&sid=tyy%2C4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_2_na_na_ps&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_2_na_na_ps&as-pos=1&as-type=RECENT&suggestionId=samsung+mobiles%7CMobiles&equestId=346f99ae-2791-4d89-b63a-2e4af06e0a63")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')

product=[]
price=[]
actual_price=[]
features=[]
discount=[]
rating=[]
stars=[]
lst = ['samsung', 'redmi', 'realme', 'vivo', 'motto']

n_pages = 0
for page in range(1, 15):
    n_pages+=1
    res = requests.get(f"https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={lst}+mobiles&sid=tyy%2C4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_2_na_na_ps&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_2_na_na_ps&as-pos=1&as-type=RECENT&suggestionId=samsung+mobiles%7CMobiles&equestId=346f99ae-2791-4d89-b63a-2e4af06e0a63&page="+str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    mobile_data = soup.find_all("div", class_="_1YokD2")
    for data in mobile_data:
    
    product_= data.find_all("div", class_="_4rR01T")
    for i in product_:
        d=i.text
        product.append(d)
    
    price_ = data.find_all("div", class_="_30jeq3")
    for i in price_:
        d=i.text
        price.append(d)
    
    actual_price_ = data.find_all("div", class_="_3I9_wc")
    for i in actual_price_:
        d=i.text
        actual_price.append(d)

    features_ = data.find_all("ul", class_="_1xgFaf")
    for i in features_:
        d=i.text
        features.append(d)

    discount_ = data.find_all("span", class_="_3Ay6Sb")
    for i in discount_:
        d=i.text
        discount.append(d)

    rating_ = data.find_all("span", class_="_2_R_DZ")
    for i in rating_:
        d=i.text
        rating.append(d)

    stars_ = data.find_all("div", class_="_3LWZlK")
    for i in stars_:
        d=i.text
        stars.append(d)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['product']=product
df['price']=price
df['actual_price']=actual_price
df['features']=features
df['discount']=discount
df['rating']=rating
df['stars']=stars
```

**This is the error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 df['product']=product
      2 df['price']=price
----> 3 df['actual_price']=actual_price
      4 df['features']=features
      5 df['discount']=discount

File d:\datascience-main\datascience-main\ds\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3655, in DataFrame.__setitem__(self, key, value)
   3652     self._setitem_array([key], value)
   3653 else:
   3654     # set column
-> 3655     self._set_item(key, value)

File d:\datascience-main\datascience-main\ds\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3832, in DataFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   3822 def _set_item(self, key, value) -> None:
   3823     """
   3824     Add series to DataFrame in specified column.
   3825 
   (...)
   3830     ensure homogeneity.
   3831     """
-> 3832     value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   3834     if (
   3835         key in self.columns
   3836         and value.ndim == 1
   3837         and not is_extension_array_dtype(value)
   3838     ):
   3839         # broadcast across multiple columns if necessary
   3840         if not self.columns.is_unique or isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):

File d:\datascience-main\datascience-main\ds\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:4535, in DataFrame._sanitize_column(self, value)
   4532     return _reindex_for_setitem(value, self.index)
   4534 if is_list_like(value):
-> 4535     com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
   4536 return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True)

File d:\datascience-main\datascience-main\ds\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py:557, in require_length_match(data, index)
    553 """
    554 Check the length of data matches the length of the index.
    555 """
    556 if len(data) != len(index):
--> 557     raise ValueError(
    558         "Length of values "
    559         f"({len(data)}) "
    560         "does not match length of index "
    561         f"({len(index)})"
    562     )

ValueError: Length of values (1233) does not match length of index (1344)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid these bunch of lists, that will lead in 90% cases to errors, cause of different lengths. Instead iterate each row, scrape all the information need and store them in a single list with dicts. Also try to avoid selections by dynamic classes and use more of the HTML structure.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = []

n_pages = 0
for page in range(1,15):
    n_pages+=1
    res = requests.get(f"https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={lst}+mobiles&sid=tyy%2C4io&as=on&as-show=on&otracker=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_2_na_na_ps&otracker1=AS_QueryStore_OrganicAutoSuggest_1_2_na_na_ps&as-pos=1&as-type=RECENT&suggestionId=samsung+mobiles%7CMobiles&equestId=346f99ae-2791-4d89-b63a-2e4af06e0a63&page="+str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    mobile_data = soup.select('a:-soup-contains("Add to Compare")')
    
    for e in mobile_data:
        prices = list(e.select_one('div.row div.col + div.col > div').stripped_strings)

        data.append({
            'title':e.select_one('div.row div.col > div').text,
            'price_actual':prices[0][1:],
            'price':prices[2] if len(prices) >= 2 else prices[0][1:],
            'features':list(e.ul.stripped_strings),
            'discount': e.select_one('div.row div.col + div.col span').text.split('%')[0] if e.select_one('div.row div.col + div.col span') else None,
            'stars': e.select_one('[id^="productRating"]').text if e.select_one('[id^="productRating"]') else None,
            'ratings':e.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Ratings")').text.split()[0] if e.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Ratings")') else None
            }
        )
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | title | price_actual | price | features | discount | stars | ratings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | realme C25_Y (Metal Grey, 128 GB) | 11,999 | 13,999 | ['4 GB RAM | 128 GB ROM', '16.51 cm (6.5 inch) HD+ Display', '50MP + 2MP + 2MP | 8MP Front Camera', '5000 mAh LiPo Battery', 'Unisoc T618 Processor', '1 Year Domestic Warranty'] | 14 | 4.4 | 36,858 |
| 1 | realme C25_Y (Metal Grey, 64 GB) | 10,999 | 12,999 | ['4 GB RAM | 64 GB ROM', '16.51 cm (6.5 inch) HD+ Display', '50MP + 2MP + 2MP | 8MP Front Camera', '5000 mAh LiPo Battery', 'Unisoc T618 Processor', '1 Year Domestic Warranty'] | 15 | 4.4 | 36,858 |
| 2 | realme C31 (Dark Green, 32 GB) | 9,299 | 10,999 | ['3 GB RAM | 32 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 1 TB', '16.56 cm (6.52 inch) HD Display', '13MP + 2MP + 0.3MP | 5MP Front Camera', '5000 mAh Battery', 'Unisoc T612 Processor', '1 Year Warranty for Phone and 6 Months Warranty for In-Box Accessories'] | 15 | 4.6 | 29,060 |
| 3 | realme C31 (Light Silver, 32 GB) | 9,299 | 10,999 | ['3 GB RAM | 32 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 1 TB', '16.56 cm (6.52 inch) HD Display', '13MP + 2MP + 0.3MP | 5MP Front Camera', '5000 mAh Battery', 'Unisoc T612 Processor', '1 Year Warranty for Phone and 6 Months Warranty for In-Box Accessories'] | 15 | 4.6 | 29,060 |
| 4 | realme C31 (Dark Green, 64 GB) | 9,999 | 11,999 | ['4 GB RAM | 64 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 1 TB', '16.56 cm (6.52 inch) HD Display', '13MP + 2MP + 0.3MP | 5MP Front Camera', '5000 mAh Battery', 'Unisoc T612 Processor', '1 Year Warranty for Phone and 6 Months Warranty for In-Box Accessories'] | 16 | 4.4 | 23,910 |

...